# Communication between different services in AWS ECS

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I am running two docker containers(One for Tomcat and other one for MySql) on AWS ECS services but both containers are generated from different task definition of different services. Currently i have configured using hostname and IP address. But i want discover them without hardcoding IP address just using with the help of services. How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put each service behind an ALB.
Then use ALB uri in container by env var for example.

By the way you should put only stateless container in ECS. I advice you to put Sql service in a RDS or something like that.

Comment: Suppose if i have 100 services. 50 of them are using TCP connection and remaining 50 are using HTTP. But out of 50 HTTP connection only 25 API are for expose to world. Remaining 25 are communicating with these 25 services to do some operation. Do you think i should use only single public load balancer to handle all of these or i should use two load balancer one for public API and other one that would be private for internal communcation. Should i create network load balancer for remaining 50 API with which i can make only TCP connection. HTTP load balancer can not be used here.

Comment: When i ask exactly same question to my Aws Ecs Architect, he tell me to put each service behind an ALB (or target group). After that you can have 1 ALB with 50 redirects rules or 50 ALB with 1 rule doesnt matter.